# Send result of function to child component

Tags: angular

I'm trying this:

```
<image-card *ngFor="let user of speakers; let i = index" [_follow]="checkFollow(user.userId)"></image-card>
```

checkFollow(id) return true or false, but this execute the function constantly. What is wrong with it?

Function:

```
checkFollow(id: number) {
let follow: boolean = false;
let userFollowing: string[] = this.dataUser.userFollowing.split(',');
userFollowing.forEach(userId => {
  if (userId == id.toString()) follow = true;
});
return follow; }
```

@Input in child component:

```
@Input() _follow: boolean = false;
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "this execute the function constantly"?

Comment: I don't know why, but that function runs every few seconds. I will edit the post so you can see the function and the @Input

Comment: This is expected behavior. This will be called multiple times. This is how Change Detection in Angular works. Since the property that you have bounded is a function which will be resolved at runtime, so Angular constantly keeps a check to see if function value has changed. It is a good practice to limit use of methods in template. You can read more on this - https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496